# How to effectively transition from one career path in which you are highly qualified to another in which you are not?

Tags: software-industry, resume, job-search, job-change, career-switch

Context: From the moment I was born, my family pushed me to pursue a career in the IT industry. My education was dramatically accelerated, and I managed to pick up extensive work experience, highly-sought-after qualifications, and accolades in programming competitions. Seeing as the ball on my career got rolling so early, it accelerated and snowballed and it's now got to the point where I get a generous job offer every week on LinkedIn. For a couple of years, Google recruiters kept on contacting me trying to headhunt me.

The problem is, *I hate working in the Technology industry*. My real passion is in the humanities: Specifically Ministry, Missionary Work, Comparative Religion, Academia, Comparative Theology, World Philosophy and Languages. Now, while I *do* have lots of skills and experience in both Technology and these aforementioned Humanities subjects, unfortunately my Resume has nothing but Technology related stuff on it. I'm hyper-qualified and have concrete experience in Tech, but when it comes to humanities my experience is entirely made up of my hobbies and my relevant skills are not backed up with any formal qualifications.

How does one go about changing their career trajectory in such circumstances? I am 27 years old and on my resume 15 of those years are entirely Tech-related. I know I'm still (relatively) young and a career change is possible, but at the same time it's daunting because I'm basically turning my back on *everything* that my life has been building towards so far and rolling the dice by trying to move into a field where I've got *next to nothing* in the way of formal qualifications and experience (despite the fact that I *do* have the relevant skills. For example I can read Latin, Ancient Greek, Sanskrit, Classical Chinese etc fairly well, and have been reading Philosophy and Theology books relentlessly on the side during my IT career)

It's rough going from getting a ludicrously lucrative job offer every week in IT, to not even knowing how to begin to break-in in the Humanities. I've spent the past 3 years back at uni refining the relevant skills, and so do have some basic formal experience, but I haven't yet graduated with any *significant* qualifications which I can put on my resume. It would be nice if I could get some paid experience while I complete my MA (eg, as a research assistant, or perhaps as a paid member of a ministry or missionary team).

Just wondering how to navigate this. (Important note, I fully understand that I am taking a massive cut to my income by doing this, but this doesn't phase me. No amount of zeros appended to the salary figure can compensate for a lifetime wasted working on a career which I hate)

Comment: What exactly do you think you need?  There are legion unpaid missionary and ministry positions if you just need some experience.  Ignore your tech experience - what specific kind of job do you want to do and how to random new grads get into it?  “Humanities” is an excessively vague term, you can probably get a substitute teacher gig for middle school English pretty readily...

Comment: @mxyzplk-SEstopbeingevil That was enough to be an answer.

Comment: Or a close vote as unclear.

Comment: Don't have an answer to your question. However just out of curiosity what profession do you have in mind where it is useful that you can read Latin, ancient Greek, Sanskrit and classical Chinese (impressive as that is)?

Comment: @mxyzplk-SEstopbeingevil If he wants to get into academia, he’d probably be better off applying for a tutoring position at a university. Some of them value people with industry experience, especially in IT. Of course, then he’ll be teaching about the field he says he hates.

Comment: @nick012000 I actually enjoy **teaching** programming and technology. I just can't stand working in the industry. I would be open to tutoring programming, i'm just concerned that it's not super-relevant to the direction I want to head, which is more focused on ancient languages and theology

Comment: Not exactly an answer but a resource: follow some of the names on #classicstwitter and you'll see a lot of people looking at questions of how to build a career on a love for the same subjects you're looking at. There are a lot of fledgeling projects that marry technology and classical language pedegogy where I'm sure your prior qualifications would serve well.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to transition is to start working SPECIFICALLY for one of those groups, like a university or a charity that does the kind of work you want to do, and then start to transition over by taking on work of the kind you want to do.

Be aware, that as long as you are there and they KNOW you do IT, you will be summoned during tough times.  But, build up experience doing a hybrid job like that, and you may be able to do a full internal transfer.

Failing that, apply to another organization once you have the experience, and then omit or downplay any IT experience when applying for the next job.

Also, you can do volunteer work on the side to get experience.  Since you want to break into the humanities, you could do volunteer work for charities who would LOVE to have the help, and then once you get known, and build connections with that charity, apply for a paying position.

The book "What color is your parachute" can help with ideas.

Comment: This, humanities and religious organisations are not known to be tech savy, this is a great entry-way, you then just need to have a way to pivot when you are ready to.

Answer (score 6):

### Build up enough money, then try volunteering.

"Ministry, Missionary Work, Comparative Religion, Academia, Comparative Theology, World Philosophy and Languages" covers a pretty broad area.  It's basically a spectrum across of "stuff about religion", "stuff about foreign countries" and "academia".  Going into academia professionally is hard road, with a lot of competition.  The intersection of "religion" and "foreign countries", though, is pretty much straight-up missionary work.  A stint of a year or two, volunteering as a missionary in a foreign country will teach you a lot of things about the field, and will look good on the resume of almost anywhere you'd want to apply to.  It's volunteering, so you won't be getting paid, but right now you have a job that pays extraordinarily well compared to the standard of living that you're targeting anyway.  Grit your teeth and bear it long enough to build up a nest egg that will see you through your volunteer experience, and then see you through some distance further down the path, to give you flexibility about what you do afterwards.

I'd suggest that you try not to burn your bridges as you go, though.  While I absolutely respect your desire to get away from tech, the fact is that the ability to fall back on a highly lucrative job that you hate when you absolutely have to is *useful*.  Emergency backup plans are often unpleasant.

Comment: You don't need to build up money to volunteer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to spend less time studying theology and more time networking within your church. All major denominations have pathways to what you are looking for. There is a lot of logistics involved and it's a broad industry. Theological colleges are also easy to find.

None of it is difficult once you start interacting with the right people. You won't find these people in a book, but you will find them using a search engine. So get involved with your church. If you want to be a missionary but don't actually have a church or preference.... then you're missing the point. It's a calling, not a lifestyle choice.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving tech at your age is extremely smart move. As most age discrimination starts in late 20s, when age starts to show. It is pretty humbling (in bad way), speaking from personal experience. You have experience in desired field so start seeking dream job, use IT as financial stepping stone, accept lurcative offers if they pay more but don't over rely on it. Tech is brutal and constantly shifting ground, espacially for someone approaching 30 (age when you desire spiritual growth over material an gravitate towards wisdom).  As to would-be downvoters, please don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: Overall, you are incorrect, at least for the US job market.  If you're managing your career right, tech pays more as you get older, not less.

Comment: Paycheck increases, but ability to find a job in case you get fired decreases, somewhere on mid thirties lies "oh my, i'm screwed" threshold, I've seen few people retire to tropical islands, thanks to smart savings and  career choices. But I also seen whole teams laid off. And you really really don't want to be in second category, especially when you are married, have kids, and elderly parents to take care of. When you are on wrong side of thirty, single, free spirited 20 somethings can just beat you by virtue of being able to stay up until 3:00 and working for 1/3 of your salary @Ben Barden

Answer (score -2):

In my experience, carrier switch is not an easy task but attainable.

Education / time and entry level position is usually the key components of a new carrier

P.S.
@Llewellyn , @Old_Lamplighter
This is the only answer to the OPs question given the general nature of the question.

Carrier switch to unrelated field cannot, usually, be done to better than entry level position without dedicated higher education in the new field.
Perhaps connections can help, but their existence was not mentioned.

Comment: This answer is a bit too generic to be useful advice. Could you expand a bit?

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer